# How to structure HTML data to be displayed as a tree with jsTree

Tags: html, jstree, html-lists

I'm new with jsTree and I would like to create a tree starting from a `<ul>` and `<li>` list inside my HTML page. This using `html_data` plugin (I hope it's the right way).

I'm wondering: **which is the correct way** to write in HTML the data that will be turned into a tree by jsTree?

[jsTree documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/html_data) suggests this one:

```
<li>
    <a href="some_value_here">Node title</a>
    <!-- UL node only needed for children - omit if there are no children -->
    <ul>
        <!-- Children LI nodes here -->
    </ul>
</li>
```

But it doesn't specify where to put the `id` attribute that jsTree uses to refer to the data.

Moreover it doesn't seem to work so well. I've seen someone who embeds that code with a `<div>` and a `<ul>` tags. For instance:

```
<div id="categories">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Category 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubCategory 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubCategory 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Category 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note that the `id` in the div tag. 
Is this a correct way?
For me it seems not so comfortable using `<a href="#">` tags only to write the text of a node... And if I use a `<span>` I loose the item icon...

Hope someone has a clearer head than mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the pattern used by jsTree to draw the tree:

```
<div id="mytree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Node 1</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Node 1.1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Node 1.2</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Node 1.2.1</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Node 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

That is each node has the structure recommended by jsTree documentation:

```
<li>
    <a href="some_value_here">Node title</a>
    <!-- UL node only needed for children - omit if there are no children -->
    <ul>
        <!-- Children LI nodes here (recursively apply the same pattern)-->
    </ul>
</li>
```

And all the structure must be wrapped with (what documentation doesn't say):

```
<div id="mytree">
    <ul>
        <!-- all the tree here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This was very helpful to me today.  Ridiculous they don't fix such a simple omission in the documentation.